# Assigning default value while creating migration file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

```
rails generate migration AddRetweetsCountToTweet retweets_count:integer
```

Ok I use above line to create migration file that automatically generates code in the generated file to add a column to a model Tweet with datatype integer. Now I want to add default value to the added column while generating the migration file. Is that possible? I googled it but couldn't find. Guys need help.

Comment: see the RailsGuide on the subject: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html the information you are looking for is in the first section Anatomy of a Migration

Comment: I know exactly what you mean. I kept trying to set a default value as well, and it was sort of a pain trying to find information. Just generating the bare SQL was easier, though then there's no migration in version control.

Answer (score 187, accepted):

Default migration generator does not handle default values ([column modifiers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#column-modifiers) are supported but do not include `default` or `null`), but you could create your own generator.

You can also manually update the migration file prior to running `rake db:migrate` by adding the options to `add_column`:

`add_column :tweet, :retweets_count, :integer, :null => false, :default => 0`

... and read [Rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/)

Comment: Ok thanks for the reply. I thought it would be great if default migration generator would provide option to handle default values so that I do not have to edit the migration file after being generated in order to specify default value.

Answer (score 54):

```
t.integer :retweets_count, :default => 0
```

... should work.

See the [Rails guide on migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html)

Answer (score 12):

Yes, I couldn't see how to use 'default' in the migration generator command either but was able to specify a default value for a new string column as follows by amending the generated migration file before applying "rake db:migrate":

```
class AddColumnToWidgets < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :widgets, :colour, :string, default: 'red'
  end
end
```

This adds a new column called 'colour' to my 'Widget' model and sets the default 'colour' of new widgets to 'red'.

Comment: (This was in Rails 4.2.)

Answer (score 5):

I tried t.boolean :active, :default => 1 in migration file for creating entire table. After ran that migration when i checked in db it made as null. Even though i told default as "1". After that slightly i changed migration file like this then it worked for me for setting default value on create table migration file.

t.boolean :active, :null => false,:default =>1. Worked for me.

My Rails framework version is 4.0.0

Answer (score 3):

You would have to first create your migration for the model basics then you create another migration to modify your previous using the change_column ...

```
def change
    change_column :widgets, :colour, :string, default: 'red'
end
```