# heroku: PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: “”

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I have a currency(ccy) column on my event model and it's currently a string, I'd like to change it to a integer.

Although it works on my local environment, the following error was displayed when I try `heroku run rake db:migrate` to heroku.

```
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: ""
: ALTER TABLE "events" ALTER COLUMN "ccy" TYPE integer USING CAST(ccy AS integer)
```

The migration file as below.

```
class ChangeCcyToEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :events, :ccy, 'integer USING CAST(ccy AS integer)'
  end
end
```

I found the similar question [PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "M"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20715190/pginvalidtextrepresentation-error-invalid-input-syntax-for-integer-m), so I changed migration file as below. But the result is the same.

```
class ChangeCcyToEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    Event.where(ccy: '').update_all(ccy: '')
    change_column :events, :ccy, 'integer USING CAST(ccy AS integer)'
  end
end
```

There is no value in all `ccy` column so far.

It would be appreciated if you could give me any advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your migration is trying to convert a `""` into an integer, which postgres complais about it (and it should, because it's not a valid conversion).

You should update your content for invalid cases before changing the column type:

```
class ChangeCcyToEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    Event.where("ccy IS NULL OR ccy = ''").update_all({ccy: '0'})
    change_column :events, :ccy, 'integer USING CAST(ccy AS integer)'
  end

  def down
    raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
  end
end
```

Perhaps is not complaining in development (localhost) because you're using a different version of postgreSQL than Heroku.

Next time, try using [default values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167994/assigning-default-value-while-creating-migration-file) in migrations for this kind of columns.

Comment: You can't use `return` like that `ruby != javascript` , it should raise an error `LocalJumpError: unexpected return`. I think you mean `next`

Comment: @Зелёный You're right! I have changed it to a `next` command.

Comment: Also it is work for [`update_all`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all) method.

Comment: And last, the [`change_column`](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#changing-columns)method is *irreversible*.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and comment, @Wikiti and @Зелёный. Although I tried the migration file which @Wikiti answered, the following error was appeared.`StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

uninitialized constant ChangeCcyToEvents::Events` At the middle of error `NameError: uninitialized constant ChangeCcyToEvents::Events` was displayed. It would be appreciated if you could give me any advice.

Comment: @SamuraiBlue My fault! It's not `Events`, but `Event`. Model names are singular, and table names are plural