# PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: “aaa”

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have followed all suggestions from similar questions but none has solved my problem.
I want to change the field `gl_code` from `string` to `integer` and have tried the following:

```
class ChangeCategoryGlCode < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    # Category.all.each { |cat| cat.update(gl_code: cat.gl_code.to_i) }
    Category.where("gl_code IS NULL OR gl_code = ''").update_all({gl_code: '0'})
    # change_column :categories, :gl_code, :integer, using: 'gl_code::integer'
    change_column :categories, :gl_code, 'integer USING CAST(gl_code AS integer)'
  end
end
```

But nothing seems to work. I even ssh'd to the server and run the commands manually but whenever I try to deploy it fails at `rake db:migrate` with the error above.

Any suggestions/hints are welcome.

Previous questrions [(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37767693/heroku-pginvalidtextrepresentation-error-invalid-input-syntax-for-integer), [(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20715190/pginvalidtextrepresentation-error-invalid-input-syntax-for-integer-m)

Edit: If that matters, I am using the Apartment gem, and have tried changing the `gl_code` for `Category` for each tenant.

Comment: The entry `aaa` in your `gl_code` column cannot be converted to an integer. What's unclear about that?

Comment: Have you tried looking at your data to see if there's a `gl_code` 'aaa' lying around anywhere?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, @dmfay I have searched for `gl_code` "aaa" but there is no item with a code like that.
`Category.where(gl_code: "aaa")` returns an empty list.
I also tried 
`Category.all.each { |c| puts c.gl_code if c.gl_code.kind_of?(String)  }`
and I still get nothing.
Tbh I remember adding a gl_code like that (for testing purposes) but shouldn't what I tried return something?

Comment: In my migration file `Category.all.each { |cat| cat.update(gl_code: cat.gl_code.to_i) }` or
   ` Category.where("gl_code IS NULL OR gl_code = ''").update_all({gl_code: '0'})`. Those should have fixed any `gl_code` that is a string, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Use PL/pgSQL to find the guilty row:

```
DO
$$DECLARE
   v_gl_code text;
   v_id bigint;
BEGIN
   FOR v_id, v_gl_code IN
      SELECT id, gl_code FROM category
   LOOP
      BEGIN
         PERFORM v_gl_code::integer;
      EXCEPTION
         WHEN OTHERS THEN
            RAISE NOTICE 'Bad value at id = %', v_id;
      END;
   END LOOP;
END;$$;
```

Comment: I tried this and got nothing. 
I eventually dropped the db and created a new one, as it was a dev db, but it is not the solution I wanted, so marking my action as correct would not feel right.
Thank you for the help.