# Add to Integer Variable from Rails Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This should be a fairly simple error to fix (I hope).  When a `joke` on my app is approved, I want that `user` to be awarded 5 `manpoints` (don't ask).  I currently have this in my 'jokes_controller`:

```
  def approve
    @joke = Joke.find(params[:id])
    @joke.update_attributes(approved: true)
    if @joke.user.manpoints = nil
      @joke.user.manpoints = 5
    else
      @joke.user.manpoints += 5
    end
    @joke.save
    redirect_to jokes_path
  end
```

I'm getting this error when I try to approve a joke:

```
undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
```

I thought += was the "Ruby way" to do this?  Can anyone set me straight?

Comment: try changing `@joke.user.manpoints = nil` to `@joke.user.manpoints.nil?` and `@joke.user.manpoints == nil` should be the correct syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `=` in `if` condition to `==`. I assume you need to compare `manpoints` with `nil`, not to assign `nil` to manpoints.
It should be like:

```
if @joke.user.manpoints == nil
  ...
```

You can omit `==` operator here:

```
unless @joke.user.manpoints
  ...
```

PS. Why are you excepting that `manpoints` will be `nil`?

Comment: Those changes get rid of the error, but the `user`'s `manpoints` are still `nil` after the approve action.

Comment: You need to save the `user` instance.
Save it with `@joke.user.save`.

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome :)
btw, you can avoid the comparison. Use default value with migration. 
[related info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167994/assigning-default-value-while-creating-migration-file)